# Is a silhouette photo possible with a glass object?

Tags: silhouette

I have a colored blown glass sculpture and tried to take a silhouette photo of it using different settings on my camera but couldn't find any that would successfully do it without making the entire picture extremely dark. Is it possible at all to take the photo or would the light always pass through the sculpture?

Comment: Possibly helpful? https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90538/57929

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to show the shape of the sculpture without having any detail inside of it, you could use [rim lighting](https://petapixel.com/2016/06/06/basic-rim-lighting-striplight/):

[image: Glass rim lighting]

You're right, almost the entire picture is extremely dark (black, actually) but the specular highlights provide enough information to perfectly understand the shape of the object.

Note that the above link also mentions the opposite kind of picture (silhouette), which might be closer to what you're after:

[image: Glass silhouette]

It's a matter of taste but I find the first picture more pleasant and informative.

You'd need to light the sculpture from both sides, either with small portable [strobes](http://strobist.blogspot.com/) or continuous lighting.

Comment: Worth adding that the link shows how to achieve the opposite affect to the picture shown here - a black rim on a white background, which seems closer to what the OP is after.

Comment: @LoganPickup: You're right, thanks. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on where the sculpture is installed, you may be able to block the prominent light source from directly illuminating the back of the sculpture while at the same time allowing the background to be brightly illuminated.

If outside, it could be as simple as using a flag (any opaque object that prevents light from passing through it) between the sun and the sculpture and shooting from an angle that includes the brightly sunlit landscape in the background. You'll still have some light bleeding through the piece, but it should be much less than if the sun is allowed to directly illuminate it.

If you are in a studio, all the better. Put as much distance as you can between the sculpture and the background and light the background with strobes pointed away from the subject and towards the background. If necessary, use flags to reduce spill from the lights to your sculpture

If you save the raw file, in post processing you can adjust the highlights and shadows with your raw conversion/processing application using the sliders or curves tools.

Comment: Also, it would help if the sculpture could be temporarily filled with an opaque substance. Of course, this depends on the specific nature of the sculpture.

Answer (score 3):

As I read the question, the object is glass (light will pass through), but it is a color (it will filter the light passing through).  Since you want the silhouette, I'll also assume taking a black and white photo is acceptable.  Find a filter of the opposite color (look at a color wheel for a suggestion) and this will darken the color of the object and the shadow passing through.  If you cannot find such a filter, you can play with the color temperature setting of your camera or maybe one of those LED bulbs where you can tune the color.

Another option would be a polarizing filter.  Most crafted objects would not have the attributes for the light to respond, but odd stuff can happen.

I think doing it at the camera rather than photo-editing makes it easier to see the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to prevent as much light as possible from falling onto the glass object.  Understand that a silhouette is basically a very, very underexposed element within the frame that is juxtaposed in front of a brighter background.  But with glass, light from the brighter background will illuminate it.  Since your piece is brown, you will probably be able to pull it off.

Comment: Blown, not brown - we don't know what colour it is, only how it was made ;)

Comment: heh, It's OK, Frank, I misread that as "brown", too!